# submitting the different value in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having the below code to show input field with phone number in certain format. i.e., If phone number starts with 33,55 or 81 I will show it as (33) 1234-5678. If phone number starts with any other numbers, the format will be (123) 456-7890.

Now, the problem is when I submit the form, it is submitted as (33) 1234-5678. But I should submit 3312345678 and display (33) 1234-5678.

Could someone help me, how could i overcome this issue. I didnt use any jquery plugins;

```
<input id="criterion"  name= "criterion" type="tel" class="inputboxBg" size="15" maxlength="60" style="width:85%;" value="" placeholder="" onkeypress = "submitOnReturn(event);">

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery("#criterion").change(function () {
            var searchBy = jQuery('#smartWirelessSearch').val();    
            if(searchBy == 'Mobile'){
                jQuery(this).attr("criterion", $(this).val());
                var twoDigit = jQuery('#criterion').val().substr(0, 2);
                var threeDigit = jQuery('#criterion').val().substr(0, 3);
                var remainingDigits = jQuery('#criterion').val().substr(2, 10);
                if (twoDigit == '33' || twoDigit == '55' || twoDigit == '81') {
                    jQuery('#criterion').val('('+twoDigit+')'+' '+remainingDigits.substr(0,4)+'-'+remainingDigits.substr(4,8));
                } else {
                    jQuery('#criterion').val('('+threeDigit+')'+' '+remainingDigits.substr(1,3)+'-'+remainingDigits.substr(4,8));
                }
            }   
        });     
    });
```

Comment: use a hidden input to store the original value of the phone number.

Comment: @Amir Can you please give the code snippet for it

Comment: The hidden input won't help much here since with every keypress the input is being updated. 

Why don't you print out the value beneath the input box? Why are you editing the actual value of the input when users enter their number?

Comment: @Duncan The client needs in this way.. Use the same textfield to get the number and submit the non-altered number

Comment: I'd suggest using {string}.replace()

Comment: @MarkNicholas then tell the client there's a better solution. Better in the sense that it's a better user experience. E.g. when the user has to correct one of the first digits. Should he deleted both '(* and ')' leave them what happens if he deletes one and all those things. Another solution would be editing in place. So when it's an input field you display the raw value. When the user de-focus the field. You hide it and display a label with the formatted value instead

Answer (score 2):

You can change the value when the form is submitted, just before it is sent to the server:

```
$("form").on("submit", function(){
  var originalVal = $("#criterion").val();
  var newVal = originalVal.replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
  $("#criterion").val(newVal);
});
```

Comment: Is there much measurable benefit of your regex versus `.replace(/[ \(\)-]/g, "")` in this case?

Comment: @BBQSingular Not really (that I know of). Since the question is not about that, I didn't give much thought to it. OP can use whatever method he wants to strip out the unwanted characters.

Comment: @BBQSingular But thanks to your comment I realized I forgot the `g` flag.

Comment: If the user presses the browser's back button after submission, the phone number will appear unformatted. Maybe the format should be re-applied on page load with this solution.

Comment: @trincot you're right, I hadn't thought about that... then perhaps a hidden input, as others have suggested, would be a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a hidden input that you store the original value of the input before modifying it.

```
<input id="criterion"  name= "criterion" type="tel" class="inputboxBg" size="15" maxlength="60" style="width:85%;" value="" placeholder="" onkeypress = "submitOnReturn(event);">

<input type="hidden" id="org" name="org" />
```

-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#criterion").change(function () {
        var searchBy = $('#smartWirelessSearch').val();  
        $('#org').val($(this).val());
        if(searchBy == 'Mobile'){
            $(this).attr("criterion", $(this).val());
            var twoDigit = $('#criterion').val().substr(0, 2);
            var threeDigit = $('#criterion').val().substr(0, 3);
            var remainingDigits = $('#criterion').val().substr(2, 10);
            if (twoDigit == '33' || twoDigit == '55' || twoDigit == '81') {
                $('#criterion').val('('+twoDigit+')'+' '+remainingDigits.substr(0,4)+'-'+remainingDigits.substr(4,8));
            } else {
                $('#criterion').val('('+threeDigit+')'+' '+remainingDigits.substr(1,3)+'-'+remainingDigits.substr(4,8));
            }
        }   
    });     
});
```

If you need to have the original cleaned value all the time, there are many ways to do that too. One simple solution is to have clean it by your self everytime input changes.

If so, replace `$('#org').val($(this).val());` by `$('#org').val($(this).val().replace(/[^\d]/g, ''));`

This basically replaces everything that is not a digit with an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest two solutions:

## 1. Toggle Format

With this solution, you either show the formatted value in the input, or the clean digit-only value. So you would take care to show the digit-only value when the form is submitted, but also when the user edits the value (as suggested by @Rune FS):

```js
jQuery(function($) {
    function cleanMobile() {
        if ($('#smartWirelessSearch').val() == 'Mobile') {
            // Strip all non-digit characters
            $("#criterion").val($("#criterion").val().replace(/[^\d]/g, ''));
        }
    }
    function formatMobile() {
        if ($('#smartWirelessSearch').val() == 'Mobile') {
            // Apply format after first stripping all non-digit characters
            $("#criterion").val($("#criterion").val()
                .replace(/[^\d]/g, '')
                .replace(/(33|55|81|...)(.*?)(....)$/, '($1) $2-$3'));
        }
    }
    $("#myform").submit(cleanMobile);
    $("#criterion").blur(formatMobile).focus(cleanMobile).keypress(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {                    
            $(this).closest('form').submit();                
        }
    });
    // Set initial format correctly on page load
    formatMobile();
}, jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform">
    <select id="smartWirelessSearch">
        <option value="Mobile">Mobile</option>
    </select>
    <input  id="criterion"  name="criterion" type="tel" class="inputboxBg" 
            size="15" maxlength="60" style="width:85%;" value="" placeholder=""> 
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Run the snippet to see how it responds to focus and submit.

Note that the code above also:

- Uses a regular expression to format the number;
- attaches the keypress handler via code instead of the element's `onkeypress` attribute;
- defines functions for the format manipulations so these can be referenced in blur, focus and submit events;
- defines a dummy *smartWirelessSearch* element so the code is compatible with your form;
- gave the form an id *myform*, which you should replace with yours.

## 2. Use Hidden Input

If you do not want the input value to visibly change at form submission, you could add a hidden input and give that the digit-only value, like this:

```
<input id="criterionClean"  name="criterionClean"  type="hidden">
<input id="criterion"  name= "criterion" type="tel" class="inputboxBg" size="15" 
       maxlength="60" style="width:85%;" value="" placeholder="" 
       onkeypress="submitOnReturn(event);">
```

In your Javascript add one line:

```
if(searchBy == 'Mobile'){
    // ... your code ...
    // Then pass the digits only in the hidden input
    $('#criterionClean').val($(this).val().replace(/[^\d]/g, ''));
}
```

Now you'll submit both the formatted and the cleaned value. Your server code could then use the clean digit-only value.

If you prefer the clean value to be called `#criterion`, then swap the names of the two inputs in html and in your code.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities to solve this, the first is to have a second (extra) hidden `input` like:

```
<input id="criterion"  name= "criterion" type="tel" class="inputboxBg" size="15" maxlength="60" style="width:85%;" value="" placeholder="" onkeypress = "submitOnReturn(event);">
<input id="criterion_hidden"  name= "criterion_real" type="hidden" size="15" maxlength="60" value="" placeholder="" onkeypress = "submitOnReturn(event);">
```

And populate it in your jquery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery("#criterion").change(function () {
            var searchBy = jQuery('#smartWirelessSearch').val();    
            if(searchBy == 'Mobile'){
                jQuery(this).attr("criterion", $(this).val());
                var twoDigit = jQuery('#criterion').val().substr(0, 2);
                var threeDigit = jQuery('#criterion').val().substr(0, 3);
                var remainingDigits = jQuery('#criterion').val().substr(2, 10);
                $("#criterion_hidden").val(twoDigit + remainingDigits); //update it here.
                if (twoDigit == '33' || twoDigit == '55' || twoDigit == '81') {
                    jQuery('#criterion').val('('+twoDigit+')'+' '+remainingDigits.substr(0,4)+'-'+remainingDigits.substr(4,8));
                } else {
                    jQuery('#criterion').val('('+threeDigit+')'+' '+remainingDigits.substr(1,3)+'-'+remainingDigits.substr(4,8));
                }
            }   
        });     
    });
```

The other solution is to change the value on the server side (PHP?) by using a replace with a regular expression such as `/[^\d]/g`.

Answer (score 0):

On submit of the form replace input value of `( ) -` with empty string `""`.